# CMake do both add_subdirectory(dir) and install(DIRECTORY dir)

Tags: build, cmake

In my root level CMake, I want to do both:

1. install its sub-directory "dir" as is on the machine: Using install(DIRECTORY dir) command
2. execute CMakeLists.txt of this sub-directory "dir" during build: Using add_subdirectory(dir) command.

It sounds logically possible to me, but I am not sure if that is really possibly as I might be missing something here.

Can somebody please confirm if both install(DIRECTORY dir) and sub_directory(dir) can be executed on a sub-directory "dir" from its parent directory's CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: Why not try it?  They should be independent... install will just copy the whole directory somewhere else on your machine, and `add_subdirectory` will add the projects in the source directory to your build.  That said, it sounds strange to install your source directory onto the machine.... What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am installing Python modules on my machine